# Python except statement not printing

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can't get except statement to print when user doesn't enter a '?' or does an invalid entry.

```
def crossWord():
    try:
        word = strInput("Crossword Solver \nuse ? as a wildcard: ")
        w = word.lower()
        f=open("wordlist.txt", "r")
        for line in f:
            line=line.strip()
            if len(line)==len(w):
                good=1
                pos=0
                for letter in w:
                    if not letter== '?':
                        if not letter==line[pos]:
                            good=0
                    pos+=1
                if good==1:
                    print(line)
    except: 
        if line == None:
            print("No words could be found. Remember to separate with '?'")
    finally:
        f.close()
```

Comment: You don´t throw a exception. What do you expect from `except`?

Comment: Also line is not in the except's scope. It's assigned in try and not declared outside of it.

Comment: I need it to print that statement if the users input is invalid. I don't know how to do that without the except.

Comment: @scriptmonster: That's not how Python's scope works. Local variables are scoped to the whole function, not to blocks. After all, without variable declarations, there's no good way to tell that two identically-named variables in the same function are supposed to be scoped to different blocks, and there's no real benefit to be gained from block scope over function scope.

Answer (score 2):

Catching exceptions blinly is a bad approach.  In fact you don't need to use exception handling at all.

```
import re

def cross_word():
    with open('wordlist.txt') as dict_fp:
        dictionary = [line.strip().lower() for line in dict_fp]
    word = input("Crossword Solver\nuse ? as wildcard: ")
    pattern = re.compile('^'+''.join(('.' if c=='?' else re.escape(c)) for c in word)+'$')
    matches = [w for w in dictionary if pattern.match(w)] 
    if matches:
        for found in matches:
            print(found)
    else:
        print("No words could be found. Remeber to separate with '?'")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    word = strInput("Crossword Solver \nuse ? as a wildcard: ")
    w = word.lower()
    f = open("wordlist.txt", "r")
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if len(line)==len(w):
            for pos,letter in enumerate(w):
                if letter != '?' and letter != line[pos]:
                    raise    
except: 
    print("No words could be found. Remember to separate with '?'")
else:
    print(line)
finally:
    f.close()
```